# Why using aliases in the SDL in GraphQL doesn't work in a nested object when should be valid

Tags: graphql

I'm experiencing a strange issue using the aliases in GQL. When I use it inside a nested object I'm getting whatever field I decide to alias the following error

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable field xxx.yyyy.
```

Soon as I remove the aliases the value of the field is not null anymore and I cannot explain why this is happening

The original query which fails with alaises

```
query WEB_GetConsentForms($studyId: ID!) {
  informedConsentForms(
    filter: { isActiveRevision: true, statuses: [PUBLISHED], studyId: $studyId }
    sort: { orderBy: createdAt, direction: DESC }
  ) {
    nodes {
      id
      name: title
      locale
      studyId
      irb {
        id
        attachedSites {
         value: siteId
         label: name
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
  locales(studyId: $studyId) {
    nodes {
      language {
        name
        __typename
      }
      locale
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

Whatever fields I decide to alias after the **IRB** is giving me that error.
Before the nested field, everything works so for example the field `name: title` is giving me back the value.

I don't understand why that happens only for the nested fields and as I understood reading online should be valid for doing it this

Screenshots of the data are from autogenerated tests of Cypress so is fake data and safe to show

Valid

[image]

Not valid

[image]